# Continuous function with Continous right derivative must be differentiable on $[0,T]$?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I think a continuous function with continuous right derivative  must be differentiable on a closed bounded interval $[0,1]$ but I do not know how to prove it. If this is not true, can any one give me a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

This is true. One can prove something stronger with little extra effort:

If any one of the four [Dini derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative) of a continuous function $f$ is continuous at a point then $f$ is differentiable at that point. Your hypothesis is that the upper and lower right derivatives are equal and continuous.

This is proved in Bruckner, [Differentiation of Real Functions, Theorem 1.3, page 40](http://books.google.com/books?id=fXfEG-F2zJUC&pg=PA40).

Comment: Up to the right endpoint where differentiability could fail (e.g. shifting $g(x) = x \sin x$ to $f(x) = g(1-x)$).